# Java sample OAuth service flow apps for accessing Big Query

Tags: java, oauth, google-bigquery

Is there any sample Java apps that show how to access Big Query using an OAuth service flow. Most of the apps seem to show web and desktop flows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure - try something like this (below). More examples of this type of flow here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-server

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class JavaCommandLineServiceAccounts {

  private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery";
  private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  private static Bigquery bigquery;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("XXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("my_file.p12"))
        .build();

    bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName("BigQuery-Service-Accounts/0.1")
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

    Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list("publicdata");
    DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
    System.out.format("%s\n", datasetList.toPrettyString());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Took me awhile to get eclipse stood up and some other tools.